# Can Eclipse automatically add all folders labelled src to the build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, external

I have a fairly deep hierarchy of interdependent externals in a given project.

All of these externals exist in a single folder called `modules` in the root of the project.

Each of the folders I want to add to the build path are labelled as `src`.

Is there a way for Eclipse to automatically search a given folder and add all folders labelled `src` to the build path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such functionality built in eclipse. You're requirement is quite special.

All you have to do is to add entries to the projects `.classpath` file like

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="<srcfolder>"/>
```

where `<srcfolder>` is a the src folder name relative to the projects root. And refresh the project if you've edited that file with an external editor or application.

<sub>To see and edit it: simply open the Navigator view. It's hidden on the Package Explorer</sub>